# save to package.json, npm install for node modules

Tags: node.js

Saw this command npm install some_package --save, what does that mean? I know it will add dependency into package.json, but what exactly does it do? does that mean if someone do npm install it will install that module because it's in the package.json? what is it not by default add to package.json, I'm confused.

And in this page

to install I need to run

```
$ npm i youtube-api
```

What does the i mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute `npm install module_name --save` command, `npm` will add module_name to your node app's dependencies like as your said.

And when you exec `npm install` command, `npm` will download this module automatically.

`npm i youtube-api` command is meaning `npm install youtube-api`.

For more details you can read npm docs from [here.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: what is the `i` for? and what happend if I don't declare `--save`? npm will not add module_name to my node app's depencies, but what will happen actually?

Comment: i is alias for "install". If you don't declare "--save" your module will be downloaded first time but if you move your app to another directory and execute "npm install" command, npm will not download it automatically because it's wasn't added into package.json file.